# Using Clojure update-in with multiple keys

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I'm trying to apply a function to all elements in a map that match a certain key.

```
(def mymap {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"}) 
(update-in mymap [:a :b] #(str "X-" %))
```

I'm expecting

```
{:a "X-a", :c "c", :b "X-b"}
```

But I get

> ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative  clojure.lang.RT.assoc (RT.java:702)

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 11):

`update-in` is to update a single key in the map (at a particular nesting level, `[:a :b]` means update key :b inside the map value of key :a.

What you want can be done using reduce:

```
(reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (str "X-" (%1 %2)))
        mymap
        [:a :b])
```

Comment: Or `(into mymap (for [k [:a :b]] [k (str "X-" (mymap k))]))`.

Comment: @amalloy which one is more idiomatic?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generalized function:

```
(defn update-each
  "Updates each keyword listed in ks on associative structure m using fn."
  [m ks fn]
  (reduce #(update-in %1 [%2] fn) m ks))

(update-each mymap [:a :b] #(str "X-" %))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, the haspmap if first filtered, then it is mapped to the str function, and then merged with the original hashmap -

```
(def m {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"})
(def keys #{:a :b})

(->> m
    (filter (fn [[k v]] (k keys)))
    (map (fn [[k v]] [k (str "X-" v)]))
    (into {})
    (merge m))
```

Comment: Can you explain how this fixes the original problem instead of simply posting code?